# GSP taglib import

Tags: groovy, import, jstl, gsp, taglib

I'm trying to use GSP outside grails and ran to my first problem.

I cannot seem to do a taglib import in my GSPs.

Given

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

When I run my app,

I am getting a

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Creation of template failed: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: SimpleTemplateScript2.groovy: 2: expecting EOF, found 'uri' @ line 2, column 35. 1 error

```
groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet.getTemplate(TemplateServlet.java:256)
groovy.servlet.TemplateServlet.service(TemplateServlet.java:382)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:268)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:154)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:124)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:313)
org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to wait for grails 1.2 for the standalone GSP since it is currently not supported.